# How to apply 2 awks inside an IF condition?

Tags: if-statement, awk, command

I have a file with the following format:

```
name   3  4
name  -4  3
name  -5  4
name   2 -4
```

I want to make this substruction  $2-$3 and to add an extra column at the beginning of my file with the -/+ sign based on the second column to obtain the following format:

```
   - name  -1  3  4
   - name  -7 -4  3
   - name  -9 -5  4
   + name   6  2 -4
```

I used this command

```
awk '{print $1,$2-$3,$2,$3}' FILE |if ($2 < 0 ) then awk '{print "-",$0}' ; else awk '{print "+",$0}'; fi
```

Which giving:

```
   - name  -1  3  4
   - name  -7 -4  3
   - name  -9 -5  4
   - name   6  2 -4
```

I tried to "play" with curly brackets but it seems my condition stops after the first awk. What did I make wrong on my command?

Comment: @Quasímodo I edited my post...sorry for that. You are actually right.

Comment: @Quasímodo  I'm apologizing for my post's mistakes. I tried to keep it simple and explain my issue so I had to create an example of my file. :-(.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '{$1=($2>$3?"+":"-") OFS $1 OFS $2-$3} 1' Input_file
```

In case you want to have TAB separated output then try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} {$1=($2>$3?"+":"-") OFS $1 OFS $2-$3} 1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk '                                      ##Starting awk program from here.
{
  $1=($2>$3?"+":"-") OFS $1 OFS $2-$3      ##re-creating 1st field, where firstly checking if 2nd field is greater than 3rd than add + or put - then mentioning value of $1 and then subtraction of 2nd and 3rd field.
}
1                                          ##1 will print the lines.
' Input_file                               ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! works even without If statement. Is possible to give me a brief explanation of your command>?

Comment: That rebuilds only the first field actually! Nice answer.

Comment: @KGee, Added detailed explanation now in my post, kindly do check and lemme know in case of any queries here.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Thank you soo much for the explanation. Even for a newbie like me, it was totally clear :-).